# How would I be able to remove this part of the variable?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am making a code like a guessing game. The data for the guessing game is in the CSV file so I decided to use pandas. I have tried to use pandas to import my csv file, pick a random row and put the data into variables so I can use it in the rest of the code but, I can't figure out how to format the data in the variable correctly.

I've tried to split the string with split() but I am quite lost.

```
ar = pandas.read_csv('names.csv')
ar.columns = ["Song Name","Artist","Intials"]


randomsong = ar.sample(1)


songartist = randomsong["Artist"]
songname = (randomsong["Song Name"])
songintials = randomsong["Intials"]


print(songname)
```

My CSV file looks like this.

```
Song Name,Artist,Intials
Someone you loved,Lewis Capaldi,SYL
Bad Guy,Billie Eilish,BG
Ransom,Lil Tecca,R
Wow,Post Malone, W
```

I expect the output to be the name of the song from the csv file. For Example

```
Bad Guy
```

Instead the output is

```
1  Bad Guy
Name: Song Name, dtype:object
```

If anyone knows the solution please let me know. Thanks

Comment: songname = songname.split("*")[1] should work if the song name is always between * characters.

Comment: wat is the input?

Comment: Song Name,Artist,Intials
Someone you loved,Lewis Capaldi,SYL
Bad Guy,Billie Eilish,BG
Ransom,Lil Tecca,R
Wow,Post Malone, W                                                                                              in my csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a series object as output. You can try
randomsong["Song Name"].to_string()

Comment: Yes this seems to have helped. but now the output seems to be for example                            2 Ransom                                                                                                                                  As it is the 3rd item in the CSV file row do you know how to change this so the output for example is the song name is Ransom. It would just output Ransom

Answer (score 0):

Use `df['column].values` to get values of the column.

In your case, `songartist = randomsong["Artist"].values[0]` because you want only the first element of the returned list.